# Replace the NaN in Matrix Cell

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix C.

I want to add a calculated value in a box where there is NaN.

The solution is the matrix B.

I have the matrix and vector Ampiezza = [ 0.5 0.6 0.7]

```
C = [               
    0.41 6.36   15.44
    0.28 6.37   15.03
    0.25 6.05   14.90
    0.25 6.05   13.50
    NaN  6.05   12.64
    NaN  6.05   12.19
    NaN  5.09   11.81
    NaN  4.45   9.29
    NaN  3.82   9.23
    NaN  3.82   8.82
    NaN  3.50   8.43
    NaN  2.54   8.18
    NaN  2.22   8.15
    NaN  NaN    5.60
    NaN  NaN    NaN
    NaN  NaN    NaN
    NaN  NaN    NaN 
                          ]
```

Ampiezza = [ 0.5 0.6 0.7]

```
B = [       
    0.41  6.36  15.44
    0.28  6.37  15.03
    0.25  6.05  14.90
    0.25  6.05  13.50
    0.75  6.05  12.64
    NaN   6.05  12.19
    NaN   5.09  11.81
    NaN   4.45  9.29
    NaN   3.82  9.23
    NaN   3.82  8.82
    NaN   3.50  8.43
    NaN   2.54  8.18
    NaN   2.22  8.15
    NaN   2.72  5.60
    NaN   NaN   6.10
    NaN   NaN   NaN
    NaN   NaN   NaN
                        ]
```

example:

```
[Row4, Col1] = 0.25 
I need to replace the NaN in [Row5, Col1] and add 
[Row5, Col1] = [Row4, Col1] + 0.5; 
but 
for i = 6:17 
[Row (i), Col1] = NaN 
I have to do this for all the columns 

[Row13, Col2] = 2.22 

[Row14, Col2] = [Row13, Col2] + 0.6; 

but 
for i = 3:17 
[Row (i), Col1] = NaN
```

I have to make this work for a matrix (30,14) and the vector is Ampiezza (1,14)

Comment: Consider revising your title or even the first few sentences of your question so it's obvious what you're even asking. What's the problem you're running into? What is the fix you're looking for? "Can you help me" is not a helpful title.

Comment: Sorry Magsol,I'm new and I do not speak English very well. 
I need help solving a problem

Comment: @Antonio The language is OK; that's not the problem. The thing is, you are not specifying where exactly you are getting into problems. Or perhaps provide a minimal example of input and desired output

Comment: @LuisMendo si me das tu correo te pedo enviar el file de matlab con la Matriz

Comment: @Antonio Sorry, I don't give my email for StackOverflow questions. Sei italiano? Io ne parlo un po' :-)

Comment: si @LuisMendo pero parlo abbastanza bene spagnolo. Adesso il problema si capisce? io ho una matrice come quella che vedi su, solo che è 30x14.

Comment: @Antonio I got your question now. Working on it

Comment: Tnk @LuisMendo tomorrow in the morning see. Lo miro y te voy a decir algo. Es que aqui no se pueden enviar los file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that every column of `C` contains at least one numeric entry and then at least one `NaN` (as in your example):

```
[~, col] = max(isnan(C)); %// find index of first NaN column
ind = col + (0:size(C,2)-1)*size(C,1); %// convert to linear index
B = C; %// initiallize B
B(ind) = B(ind-1) + Ampiezza; %// change entries as desired
```

Comment: You have written a very good solution, very helpful and thank you very much.
I'm sorry to here that you can not attach files

Comment: You're welcome! As for attaching files: the idea is that you should post a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not necessarily your actual data; and thus attachments are not usually needed. On the rare occasions that people here need attachments, they use some external service and paste the link in their question. Buon fine settimana!

Comment: Grazie @LuisMendo per la spiegazione e la pazienza.